# error: cannot find symbol variable toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I'm new to Android. I'm getting the above titles error when I try to add a Toolbar to my Android java code. There's an answer titled with the same issue in Stackoverflow saying make a toolbar layout and include it to my required layout . I have tried that also. But it didn't solved my issue.

```
package com.locationtracker2019;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;

public class ListOnline extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Firebase
    DatabaseReference onlineRef, currentUserRef, counterRef;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, ListOnlineViewHolder> adapter;

    //View
    RecyclerView listOnline;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_online);

        //Init View
        listOnline = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listOnline);
        listOnline.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager (this);
        listOnline.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        //set Toolbar and Logout / Join menu
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);         <!--line1-->
        toolbar.setTitle("LocationTracker2019");                        <!--line2-->

    }
}
```

In line1 **(Toolbar)** and in line2 **setTitle** are underlined with red.

Here is my build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.locationtracker2019"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0"
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0"
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0"


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Is there something wrong with SDK versions?

Comment: add your layout and confirm your toolbar id is correct

Comment: maybe adding `import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` instead of `import android.widget.Toolbar`?

Answer (score 2):

Adding below solved my problem

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

And I have removed

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

Thank you @Lino